# How to segregate string into different column in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab

How to segregate `ddmmyyhhmmss` (`day`, `month`, `year`, `hour`, `minute`, `second`) 12 digit number and put in the separate 6 column in `MATLAB`? I need 7 column now in total. For example, I have following string

```
051210151255 (which is 05 day, 12 month, 2010 year, 15 hours, 12 minute, 55 second)
```

Now I need 7 column (`whole 12 digit number, dd, mm, yy, hh, mm, ss`)

Comment: Hint: The nth digit is `(x/(10^n)) % 10` where `^` is the exponentiation operator and `%` is the modulus operator

Answer (score 0):

```
d = '051210151255';
output = zeros(1, 6);
for i=1:6
   output(1, i) = str2num(d(i*2-1:i*2));
end
output = [str2num(d) output];
```

gives:

```
>> output =

     051210151255 5    12    10    15    12    55
```